# How to programmatically get access_token with authorization_code from BOX?

Tags: box-api

after reading the oauth documentation on box's website, I understand the steps to get access_token and refresh_token, which requires authorization_code.

step1: send Get request to https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&state=authenticated&redirect_uri=https://www.appfoo.com

step2: after entering credentials of box in browser and then click the "Allow" button, redirect to the specified redirect_uri with state=authenticated&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE

step3: now with the AUTHORIZATION_CODE in the redirect url from step2,  getting access_token can be done programmatically, by sending POST request to https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token with AUTHORIZATION_CODE, client_id, client_secret in body and then parsing the returned json response.

My question is:  is it possible to programmatically do step1 and step2 instead of via browser?

thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The current OAuth 2 flow requires the user to go through the browser and can't be done programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, just imitate every form with cURL and on second step post cookies.
First time you will need 3 requests, next time only one (if refresh_token isn't expired, otherwise 3 again)

Comment: please elaborate more on this, it is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The point about imitating the browser transactions is a good one but instead of using cURL you would want to use a higher level tool like mechanize (available for ruby, perl and python).  It will handle the cookies for you and can programatically traverse forms and links.  Good for page scraping and writing scripts to order hot concert tickets from TicketMaster too!

Comment: Just remember though that you are going to be embedding your actual username and password somewhere that the script can access - which sort of defeats the purpose of OATH2 where you don't have to distribute those credentials.  Still, I have a similar situation where I want a script access content so I see the point...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the authorization code, you then should be able to get the OAuth Token(access_token, refresh_token) via SDK, correct?

Comment: Congrats on your first answer on SO! If you want to give a good answer, you can provide information on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In response to aIKid, this is what I first do to get a BoxClient

```
    BoxClient client = new BoxClient(clientId, clientSecret);

    Map<String,Object> authToken = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    authToken.put("exprires_in","3600");
    authToken.put( "token_type","bearer");
    authToken.put("refresh_token", clientRefreshToken);
    authToken.put("access_token",clientAccessToken);

    BoxOAuthToken oauthToken = new BoxOAuthToken(authToken);

    client.authenticate(oauthToken);

    return client;
```

Then, I have this to create a new user,

```
BoxUser createdUser = new BoxUser();

BoxUserRequestObject createUserRequest = BoxUserRequestObject.createEnterpriseUserRequestObject("someEmail.domain.com", "test user");
        createdUser = client.getUsersManager().createEnterpriseUser(createUserRequest);
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to do the RUD part of my CRUD operations on users and groups.